# Audio Streaming from Microphone

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, naudio

I'm creating an video chat application but I'm having issues streaming microphone audio. I have video streams working already but I was hoping to find out the best method of capturing a laptop's built in microphone and stream it. At the moment I'm using a `NetworkStream` for sending the video. I have limited experience with NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/) but every example of microphone capture doesn't seem to include a `New Audio Frame` event (which is my method for sending video frames).

I've been looking at http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/ but it seems to be more than I need and doesn't cover streaming.

How do I capture microphone audio and stream it, if possible without the overhead of saving the audio to a file? I'd appreciate a simple example.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Rephrase your question to avoid the word "best."  We don't know what's "best" for you because we don't know what your specific requirements are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a new `WaveIn` object
2. call `StartRecording`
3. in the `DataAvailable` event handler, transmit `args.BytesRecorded` bytes from `args.Buffer` across the network.

Note that this will mean you are transmitting PCM, which is not very efficient. Normally for network streaming you would use a codec. In the NAudioDemo source code there is a Network Chat demo showing this in action.